# Hit the 50 questions limit with less than 50 questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, monthly-question-limit

I just tried to post a question but it's telling me that I can only post 50 questions per mont, however I've just checked and I count 49 (If I sort the question by most recent, the 50th was posted in June). Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Also why this 50 questions limit? Is it to prevent abuses? In that case, why not increase the limit as your reputation goes up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deleted questions are included in this tally, so this is why it looks a bit off to you.

Yes, this was done to prevent abuse.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks, I guess I'll have to wait a few days before posing again then. Just curious though, can a moderator overrule the block? Maybe look at the user's questions and if there's nothing really wrong or abusive, remove the block for this month?

Comment: @Laurent: No. That's really quite a lot of questions for one person to ask in a month's time - even if they *are* decent questions. And moderators really don't have the time to sit down and review them all.