# Question Limit Messed Up

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 question per month limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit)
>   [Hit the 50 questions limit with less than 50 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102269/hit-the-50-questions-limit-with-less-than-50-questions)

I tried to ask a question...But...I got this message:

```
Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period
```

1. On my profile, it says I've only asked ***46*** questions...

2.What is the point of this question limit?

Comment: Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: I've deleted 2 i believe

Comment: It also counts questions that others deleted on your behalf.

Comment: @Null - thanks for looking - I seem to recall a proposal to let users see deleted questions on their profile - might have been useful here

Comment: @AdamRackis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108077/dont-remove-deleted-questions-from-owners-view-and-let-them-see-them-regardles

Answer (score 5):

The 50 question limit includes questions you've asked, *and then subsequently deleted*.

I'll bet a hefty sum that you've deleted* at least 5 questions in the last 30 days.

---

*or, as cdeszaq points out, others may have voted and deleted questions for you

Answer (score 2):

If you had ***any*** deleted questions, it counts towards the 50 question limit.